# How To Unlock VMware For Use With Mac OS X Guests (Enable Mac OS X Virtual Machines)

Tags: 11.10, vmware

i have this problem
i'm trying to install Mac OS X Lion 10.7 on VMWare Station 8.0.0, i found some tutorials to install Mac OS X on VMWare but they all was for windows.

Although the program is same for windows and ubuntu, there was one difference which is realted to a patch used to Unlock VMware For Use With Mac OS X Guests. I had downloaded the files for that patch there was files for each OS; Windows, solaries, OSX, Ubuntu 32 and 64 bit

the problem is in installing that patch in windows you need just to run the .bat file and everything works grate but i don't know how to run it for Ubuntu 32 bit ?

the files for that patch can be found on this link

[patch files](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=220750)

and here a link to download them directly"includes additionl files"

[Direct Link](http://goo.gl/mZFNW)

so again all what i want to know is how to install the patch on Ubuntu
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the file (macosx_guest_vmware_7.tar.gz) just to see what it contains (in order to help you :-) ). Did you read the README file? Because, it has very clearly given instructions that you need to do in order to this patch to work.

Anyway, as it (README) says, you have to execute the file called "linux" as a super-user. You can become root by typing `sudo -i` in your terminal emulator (i.e. *gnome-terminal* etc.) OR else you can temporally take super-user privileges by typing `sudo` in terminal emulator.

For an example type `sudo ./linux` (I assume your current directory contains these files. If not change directories accordingly)

That script will determine your kernel version and automatically execute relevant file. That is, since you have 32bit Linux kernel, the script "linux" will automatically called the "linux_32" script.

After that you are done :-) Hope these instructions will help you... ^_^

**P.S.:** Make sure no VMs or VMWare Workstation is running while you apply this patch.

Comment: oh Sajith that is was so kind from you to download the files to help me 
but unfortunately this didn't help me when i try to use sudo ./linux

oxxy@oxxy-desktop:~/Desktop/macosx_guest_vmware-7$ ls
linux  linux_32  linux_64  macosx  README.txt  windows_32.exe  windows.bat
oxxy@oxxy-desktop:~/Desktop/macosx_guest_vmware-7$ sudo ./linux
sudo: ./linux: command not found
oxxy@oxxy-desktop:~/Desktop/macosx_guest_vmware-7$ 
this what i face
i hope that you continue helping me
regards

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't exactly the answer you're looking for. Is there any reason to use VMware at all? In the past I used VMware, but later moved to VirtualBox and haven't missed any feature yet, so maybe you could try some other virtualization solution as a workaround to your problem.

Comment: i have try VirtualBox if you can provide me with a tutorial on how to install virtualbox guest additions on the MAC OS X Lion 10.7 i will not need the VMWare 
Thanks jcollado :)

Comment: Looks like there are no VirtualBox guest additions for Mac OS. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am running vmware workstation 12 pro . [VMware unlcoker for vmware12 pro](https://mega.nz/#!PJZBnRgD!lD2ZOWXSj3pM8vnTaNnPRgnxV9hKeupWG4PQnL7GHKM) to unlock vmware and run mac osX as guest operation system in it.
In terminal type `sudo bash lix-install.sh` from downloaded file. Now you will have option to install mac osX in vmware 12 pro